# What is the purpose of the virgins girls given to the Lord in Numbers 31?

Tags: numbers

I read the other question where was explained that the virgin girls that were spare in numbers 31 had the purpose to be given in marriage of Israel people, but the portion given to the Lord? Was for exactly the same? To marry Levites and priests?

Comment: Welcome to BH. It would help if you could provide a link to the 'other question' for us. And it would help if you could quote the text in Numbers 31. You have not given the verse, just the chapter. You are asking other people to do a lot of the work that should be visible, already, in the question.

Answer (score 0):

They became part of the [Nethinim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nethinim), who were "given" to the Levites and ultimately, God.

According to [Smith's Bible Dictionary](https://biblehub.com/topical/n/nethinim.htm):

> Nethinim
>   (given, dedicated), As applied specifically to a distinct body of men connected with the services of the temple, this name first meets us in the later books of the Old Testament-- in 1 Chronicles, Ezra and Nehemiah, The word and the ideas embodied in it may, however, be traced to a much earlier period. As derived from the verb nathan , i.e. give, set apart, dedicate, it was applied to those who were pointed to the liturgical offices of the tabernacle. We must not forget that the Levites were given to Aaron and his sons, i.e. to the priests as an order, and were accordingly the first Nethinim. (Numbers 3:9; 8:19) At first they were the only attendants, and their work must have been laborious enough. The first conquests, however, brought them their share of the captive slaves of the Midianites and 320 were given to them as having charge of the tabernacle, (Numbers 31:47) while 32 only were assigned specially to the priests. This disposition to devolve the more laborious offices of their ritual upon slaves of another race showed itself again in the treatment of the Gibeonites. No addition to the number thus employed pears to have been mad ring the period of the judges, and they continued to be known by their own name as the Gibeonites. Either the massacre at Nob had involved the Gibeonites as well as the priests, (1 Samuel 22:19) or else they had fallen victims to some other outburst of Saul's fury; and though there were survivors, (2 Samuel 21:2) the number was likely to be quite inadequate for the greater stateliness of the new worship at Jerusalem. It is to this period accordingly that the origin of the class bearing this name may be traced. The Nethinim were those "whom David and the princes appointed (Heb. gave) for the service of the Levites." (Ezra 8:20) At this time the Nethinim probably lived within the precincts of the temple, doing its rougher work and so enabling the Levites to take a higher position as the religious representatives and instructors of the people. The example set by David was followed by his successor.